# How to filter all of "string" out of a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter out all rows that include this string "PRC" out of my pivot table.  I was doing this by recording a macro, but when I made the keystrokes, I got the code below that (in the macro recording) filtered each row out individually and not all rows that include "PRC".  The problem with this is when I use this macro for the next report, it filters out only the exact same rows with the strings recorded and gives me an error message when the exact same row (exact string) is not included in the next report, and then further does not filter out the different rows (new ones).  Please help:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Part Description")
    .PivotItems("PRC,4214,2.2,16.5MB,CLX,L1").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,4214Y,2.2,16.5MB,CLX,L1").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,5215,2.5,13.75MB,CLX,L1").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,6137,3.9,24.75MB,SKL,H0").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,6146,3.2,24.75MB,SKL,H0").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,6226,2.7,19.25MB,CLX,B1").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,6230N,2.3,27.5MB,CLX,B1").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,6246,3.3,24.75MB,CLX,B1").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,7251,2.1,32M,ONP,120W,B2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,7281,2.1,32M,ONP,155W,B2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,7301,2.2,64M,ONP,155W,B2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,7351,2.4,64M,ONP,155W,B2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,7351P,2.4,64M,ONP,155W,B2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,7371,3.1,64M,ONP,200W,B2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,7401,2.0,64M,ONP,155W,B2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,7401P,2.0,64M,ONP,155W,B2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,7551,2.0,64M,ONP,180W,B2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("PRC,7601,2.2,64M,ONP,180W,B2").Visible = False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `PivotItem` consist of the text "PRC" by using `Instr`, like `If InStr(PvtItm.Caption, "PRC") > 0 Then`.

**Modified Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterPivotItems()

Dim PvtItm As PivotField
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable

'Set the Pivot Table object
Set PvtTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7")

' loop through Pivot-items
For Each PvtItm In PvtTbl.PivotFields("Part Description")
    If InStr(PvtItm.Caption, "PRC") > 0 Then
        PvtItm.Value = False
    End If
Next PvtItm

End Sub
```